# Give default value if .find is equal to none Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Amazon and was trying to get the price of any item in a page, the fact is not all the items in an Amazon page have a price so sometimes it can turn out it equals to None

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools

def spider(max_pages):
    search = str(input("Search whatever you want and I'll find it on Amazon "))
    print("\n")
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
    url = "https://www.amazon.it/s/ref=sr_pg_"+ str(page) + "?rh=n%3A425916031%2Ck%3A" + search + "&page="+ str(page) + "&sort=relevancerank&keywords=" + search
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "s-access-detail-page"}):
        href = link.get("href")
        title = link.string
        print(title)
        print(single_Data(href))
        print(href)
    page += 1

def single_Data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    priceog= (soup.find("span", {"id": "priceblock_ourprice"}))
    price_in = priceog.string
    return price_in

spider(1)
```

At the end the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

I also used to run single_Data's price with a for loop like this

```
def single_Data(item_url):
source_code = requests.get(item_url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
for item_price in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"}):
    price_in= item_price.string
    return price_in
```

So how can I set that if it doesn't find any

```
("span", {"id": "priceblock_ourprice"})
```

it doesn't have to give an error or write 'None' but instead give the variable price_in the string value I want like: "There is currently no price for this item".

Thanks xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting your error message, we can see that when an item doesn't have a price, item_price == None. So therefore, you just add an if statement above "price_in= item_price.string" to check if it is None, and if so instead set price_in = "some phrase"

```
def single_Data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for item_price in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"}):
        if item_price:
            price_in = item_price.string
        else:
            price_in = "There is currently no price for this item"
    return price_in
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept writing 'None' ahah, appreciate it xx

Answer (score 0):

```
def single_Data(item_url): 
source_code = requests.get(item_url) 
plain_text = source_code.text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser") 
for item_price in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "a-link-normal"}): 
    try:
        price_in = item_price.string
    except AttributeError:
        price_in = "price not found"
return price_in
```

One of the python mantras is that it is easy to ask for forgiveness than permission. Try to extract the string, and then give the return value a default value if you can't get the string.